# how to add typing message with socket using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I wanted to know how can I add a message "user typing...", with the socket in node.js in my web application? I'm building a group chat with react and node

Comment: Broadcast an event to everyone in the channel? Like how you would broadcast a new message sent, except it's when someone is typing?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add the functionality, when someone in the room (any person), when she is typing a message, appears at the top of the screen, "{nameuser} typing...}, just like whatsapp

Comment: What about it are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm not having problems, but I want to add this functionality, but I don't know how

Comment: That's the problem. What about adding this functionality are you stuck on? Stack Overflow is not suitable for asking how to implement things, but rather it is a place to ask how you would fix something. Try to add it yourself, then when you encounter any problems with your code, come here and ask.